# Open calendar from WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, calendar

I wanted add an event to phone's calendar using my WP7 app, but some time ago I learned that's impossible. Then, I want open the phone's calendar from my app. Is this possible?

Something like the follow:

```
WebBrowserTask browserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
browserTask.URL = "vnd.youtube:[videoID]?vndapp=youtube_mobile";
browserTask.Show();
```

But calendar rather than youtube

Anyway... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot open another app from within your own app.